# $C^*$-Algebras and Gelfand Duality Reference

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-algebras

I'm interested in learning more about the duality between (locally compact) Hausdorff spaces and commutative $C^*$-algebras. Does anyone have an introductory textbook they recommend? My background in analysis consists of a year-long sequence in measure theory and complex analysis. I'm sure this duality comprises a part of most textbooks on functional analysis, so I'd be happy with any recommendations that introduce and discuss $C^*$-algebras. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I came across the textbook *An Introduction to Noncommutative Geometry* by Joseph Várilly. It contains a quick (and categorical) exposition of the Gelfand-Naimark theorem, along with a helpful table showing the dictionary between locally compact spaces and $C^*$-algebras.